# PhpMyAdmin foreign key constraint not functioning

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have watched several tutorials on setting up foreign key constraints on phpMyAdmin now, but I can never seem to make it work.

My aim is to store names in the names table, then have those names as the foreign key of the stats table, where the stats linked with each player will be stored.

[The stats table (with index)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T3H7Z.png)

(The name table is indexed in the same way as the stats, using the index button)

[The setup of the foreign key constraint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6q1Xx.png)

No connection seems to have been properly made, since attempting to display the values of statname in PHP yields nothing.

I realise that it's important for the concerning fields to have IDs, which I have created, and in the version of phpMyAdmin I have (4.5.1), ID names don't seem to be displayed in the foreign key constraints section, only the fields those IDs refer to.

I'm pretty new to this, any help and advice would be welcome.

Comment: I've done that now, but it still isn't showing any signs of success.

Comment: Sorry I got it in reverse. What does your `names` table look like? The column types should be the same *`varchar(15)`). Also, the tables must be `InnoDB`, not `MyISAM`. **update** It looks okay though - what are the contents of the two tables?

Comment: The `names` table just has the `name` field, and is indeed the same length `varchar(15)`, and they are all in `InnoDB`.

Answer (score 0):

In the player names table, make a  field (player_id) which stores the unique id of each player as the primary key which will uniquely identify the player from the table.
Next, in your stats table, take a field (player_id) amd make it as a foreign key which will reference the (player_id) field from the player table to refer the player stats in the stats table.

Comment: and yes dont forget to follow referential integrity rules otherwise you will not get any success.

Comment: No issues. In case player names becomes same, then it will raise issues. So my word of suggestion for you is that in names tables you should take an player id field to uniquely identify the players whether their names are different or same.

Comment: According to my suggestion, if player names becomes same somehow in the future, then also your database will not fail because player id will be unique whether names are same or different.

Comment: I understand the importance of using IDs when names aren't unique, but since in my case the names will be unique, does that mean there is still a way to use the name as the foreign key?

Comment: I think that foreign key will work better with integer values.

Comment: CREATE TABLE Table_1 ( 
  column_1 SMALLINT, 
  column_2 VARCHAR(4), 
  CONSTRAINT constraint_1 
      PRIMARY KEY(column_1,column_2) NOT DEFERRABLE); 

CREATE TABLE Table_2 ( 
  column_1 SMALLINT, 
  column_2 VARCHAR(4), 
  CONSTRAINT constraint_2 
      FOREIGN KEY(column_1,column_2) REFERENCES Table_1); 
-- Here the referenced unique key defaults to Table_1's primary key

Comment: Sir I think the solution above might solve your issue.

Comment: Sir, did you got the solution for your problem ?